# How to use regex's to parse a file in Java?

Tags: java, regex, parsing, expression, match

I'm trying to use a series of regular expressions to parse tokens from a file.  I need to count newlines and be able to separate tokens that don't have a space between them.  Unfortunately java.util.Scanner's findWithinHorizon() method searches the entire rest of the input stream (up to horizon) for the START of the regex match, but I want to match the regex starting at the current file position.  Specifically, I have a bunch of regex's and want to loop through them to see which one matches starting at the *current* position in the file, and then advance the file position to right after the regex match, and continue.  Is this possible?

Scanner's next() method seems to be useless for this because it enforces delimiters and the regex must match the entire token; I want to match from the current file position, get the matched string, and advance the file seek to after the match.

Comment: How big are these files? Can they be read into memory at once?

Answer (score 1):

Options:

1. Read the whole file into memory as a String. Then use `Matcher` directly at the positions you want to.
2. Use a `FileChannel` acquired from a `RandomAccessFile` as the input for the `Scanner`. You can then directly manipulate the position of the channel.
3. Use a `FileChannel` as above, but use `Matcher` directly for greater flexibility.

An example of using a Matcher with a RandomAccessFile:

```
FileChannel fc = file.getChannel();
fc.lock(); // so it doesn't change under you

ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(BUFFER_SIZE);
CharBuffer cb = bb.asCharBuffer();

fc.read(bb);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(cb);
// etc.
```

Comment: Yes I could read the file into memory.  For the second way, how would you use Scanner to match from the current position and without delimiters? For the first and third way, how do you tell Matcher to start from the current position and then get the matched string and advance beyond it for the next match?  Thanks

Comment: @MMM - You can't tell `Scanner` to ignore delimiters, as the whole purpose of it is to find delimiters.

Comment: @MMM - The match position can be controlled with `Matcher.region()`.

Comment: To use Pattern.matcher() I seem to need a CharSequence.  I can't create that on an input stream so it seems to require reading in the whole string.  How would you use FileChannel or RandomAccessFile have to not have to read in the whole string?

Comment: @MMM - If you still want to be able to match your regex for strings longer than the buffer length (unlikely) you can implement your own `CharSequence` that loads more from the channel under the hood.